# change visibility of table tr on dropdown value

Tags: c#

I am working in an asp.net web application using c#. Following is design view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"      
   Inherits="WebApplication18.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
          <div>
                <table id="tblid" runat="server">
                    <tr id="tr11" runat="server">
                     <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblselect" runat="server" Text="Select List Type">  
                          </asp:Label>         
                     </td>
                     <td>
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddllistType" runat="server"   
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddllistType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Agent" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Customer" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Branch" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trlic" runat="server" style="display:none;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblvalue" runat="server" Text="Item Types"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblItemType" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Premium" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Budget" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Normal" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my code behind

```
protected void ddllistType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        
        if (ddllistType.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            trlic.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
        else
        {
            trlic.Style.Add("display", "block");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

when user will select agent from ddllistType then trlist should get hide otherwise it should gets displayed. But the above code is not working. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Style.Add("display", "none") to hide and show the element, but I think you should use Visible property instead.

```
protected void ddllistType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (ddllistType.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            trlic.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            trlic.Visible = true;
        }

        sc1.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```